# How Google Play App Signing works

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I want to ask how google play app signing works. After I enable this feature, can I just upload my apk (signed with upload key) as usual to google play? I mean I don't need to do extra things, do I? And, google will automatically re-sign my apk with the app signing key?

And, If I want to upload my beta version to google play, does this apk already re-signed with app signing key by google?

Appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it all works automatically, and any future version of your app will be signed by Google with the app signing key.